# Removing all HTML tags from a webpage

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am doing some BASH shell scripting with `curl`. If my curl command returns any text, I know I have an error. This text returned by `curl` is usually in HTML. I figured that if I can strip out all of the HTML tags, I could display the resulting text as an error message.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
sed -E 's/<.*?>//g' <<<$output_text
```

But I get `sed: 1: "s/<.*?>//": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid`

If I replace `*?` with `*`, I don't get the error (and I don't get any text either). If I remove the *global* (`g`) flag, I get the same error.

This is on Mac OS X.

Comment: [HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). a simple example: `<img alt="<this is an image>" src="...">`

Comment: @glennjackman For a second, I thought you might be linking to one of my many posts where I make this very point. The `sed` is really just a _macguffin_. I didn't want my question closed because I _didn't show my code_. What I was really hoping for is someone saying "_Hey, idiot if you're such a Unix expert, why didn't you just use ***foo***? That's what ***foo*** is suppose to be used for. It's on all Unix/Linux operating systems._" I would do it in Perl, but Perl doesn't include any HTML parsing modules, and I can't install them in this situation. Too many systems, and I don't control them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sed doesn't support non-greedy.

try

```
's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: You might be right about that. There's a flag in `sed` (either `-E` or `-r` that will turn on advanced regular expressions, and the `sed` manpage linked to the `re_format` manpage which talked about non-greedy qualifiers. I may just have to switch to the old standby.

Comment: This worked. Here's the translated error: `Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 - Error report HTTP Status 404 - type Status reportmessage description The requested resource () is not available.Apache Tomcat/7.0.27`. That's pretty much what I wanted. Strip out the `<head>` and all of the other tags, so I can see that `404` error message a bit more cleanly.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe parser-based perl solution?

```
perl -0777 -MHTML::Strip -nlE 'say HTML::Strip->new->parse($_)' file.html
```

You must install the [HTML::Strip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Strip/Strip.pm) module with `cpan HTML::Strip` command.

**alternatively**

you can use an standard OS X  utility called: `textutil` [see the man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/textutil.1.html)

```
textutil -convert txt file.html
```

will produce `file.txt` with stripped html tags, or

```
textutil -convert txt -stdin -stdout < file.txt | some_command
```

**Another alternative**

Some systems get installed the `lynx` text-only browser. You can use the:

```
lynx -dump file.html #or
lynx -stdin -dump < file.html
```

But in your case, you can rely only on pure `sed` or `awk` solutions... IMHO.

But, if you have perl (and only haven't the HTML::Strip module) the next is still better as `sed`

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/<.*?>//sg'
```

because will remove the next (multiline and common) tag too:

```
<a
 href="#"
 class="some"
>link text</a>
```

Comment: That's the problem. This would be a simple Perl problem if I could install Perl modules. Unfortunately, my script is an installer, and I'm installing packages from Jenkins. I use a series of scripts to _remotely_ promote builds, lock builds, and change descriptions of builds. These scripts run on hundreds of servers, and I can't install Perl modules on all of these servers, and they're not really my machines. I would have to ask IT to do it. Otherwise, I'd use HTML::Strip, and LWP, and write everything in Perl.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! A Unix tool that will _convert_ the HTML stuff to plain text. I never used `textutil` and it works great. Unfortunately, our servers are Linux. :-(. I've been using Unix for almost three decades (Well, not really true, the first _Unix like_ systems I worked on were Xenix), and I couldn't think of a single tool that could do this. I like `textutil`, and it's in almost all Unix platforms, but never made it on Linux.

Comment: @DavidW. You can't ensure command availability on Linux. Some installation has some packages, others not. In your question is `OS X` therefore added the OS X solution. :) On Linux (or freebsd) it is much harder, because you can't predict what tools is installed. But, going to add an Linux solution too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '/</ {:k s/<[^>]*>//g; /</ {N; bk}}' file
```

This might fail, you should better use a [html-parsing](/questions/tagged/html-parsing) tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all HTML tags and also all script tags (and their contents), you can use the following:

```
sed 's/<script>.*<\/script>//g;/<script>/,/<\/script>/{/<script>/!{/<\/script>/!d}};s/<script>.*//g;s/.*<\/script>//g' $file -i && sed '/</ {:k s/<[^>]*>//g; /</ {N; bk}}' $file -i && sed -r '/^\s*$/d' $file -i
```