# How to remove unique values from an HTML select list with linux program like sed, awk, or grep?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, vi

I copy the HTML from a select boxes, and trying to figure out a quick way to remove the HTML so I am left with a list of names. Generally it's not a problem, but these have unique values. I would prefer using a program like grep, sed, awk or vi. Right now I have to go through manually and edit each line. Any help would be great, thank you!

```
<option value="DL_54292">(DL)finance</option>
<option value="DL_54274">(DL)sales</option>
<option value="510496">Ben Smith</option
<option value="510507">Christopher Jones</option>
<option value="510513">Dawn James</option>
<option value="510533">Joe Wilson</option>
<option value="551825">Mark Jackson</option>
<option value="510562">Ronnie Libby</option>
```

Edit: Output format suggested by Fede.

Trying to get a simple text list, with line feed or carriage return.

```
finance
sales
Ben Smith
Christopher Jones
Dawn James
Joe Wilson
Mark Jackson
Ronnie Libby
```

Comment: what output would like to have?

Comment: Just a text list, line feed

Comment: can you update the question with your desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845056/removing-all-html-tags-from-a-webpage

Comment: I've tried that James Morris, it's not working exactly,for my needs. Similar though. Thanks!

Comment: @negativerad: it works for the input you have posted in your question.

Comment: In your output this is gone `(DL)`, should it be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep to get the texts between the tags,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=>)[^<>]+' file
(DL)finance
(DL)sales
Ben Smith
Christopher Jones
Dawn James
Joe Wilson
Mark Jackson
Ronnie Libby
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned vi, you can use this line

```
:%s_^<option value=".*">\(.*\)</option>$_\1_gi


%s -> substitute in all the file
^ -> start of line
.* -> any characters
\(.*\) -> any characters, remember those.
$ -> end of line
\1 -> first remembered match
gi -> ingnore case and take all matches in line
_ -> substitution separator
```

:s is search and replace, s_foo_bar replaces foo by bar in current line

Comment: Yea this works too. I added the grep version as an alias, works easier, but I'll save this in my vi cheat sheets. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to study this: http://vimregex.com/ . It has saved me so much work these years you wouldn't believe. And you'll be able to use this knowledge with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do this:

```
awk -F"<|>" '{print $3}'
(DL)finance
(DL)sales
Ben Smith
Christopher Jones
Dawn James
Joe Wilson
Mark Jackson
Ronnie Libby
```

If I should be true to your output request the data in parentheses should be gone too:

```
awk -F"<|>" '{sub(/[^)]*)/,"",$3);print $3}'
finance
sales
Ben Smith
Christopher Jones
Dawn James
Joe Wilson
Mark Jackson
Ronnie Libby
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Notepad++, then you can use this regex:

```
.*>(.*)<.*
```

And replace with `\1`

[image]

Comment: I don't have windows, but somebody else might later. Thanks Fede.